# How to pass run-time parameter to mapper.map?

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to use mapper.map to map one IEnumerable to another with one condition.

My IEnumerables are nested at multiple levels.

```
public class ProviderResult : IMapFrom<Provider>
{
      public int ProviderId { get; set; }
      public string ProviderName { get; set; }
     public int TradeSpecificSpeedScore { get; set; }

    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
        {
            profile.CreateMap<Provider, ProviderResult>()
                .ForMember(d => d.ProviderId,
                    opt =>
                        opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
                .ForMember(d => d.ProviderName,
                    opt =>
                        opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
.ForMember(d => d.TradeSpecificSpeedScore,
                    opt =>
                        opt.Ignore());
     }
}

public class Provider
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ProviderMetrics> Metrics { get; set; } = new List<ProviderMetrics>();
}

public class ProviderMetrics
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public int? SubscriberId { get; set; }
        
        public MetricsData Data { get; set; }
}

public class MetricsData
{
 public List<TradeMetrics> Trades { get; set; } = new List<TradeMetrics>();
}

public class TradeMetrics
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double SpeedScore { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Here is something I want to do :

```
var providerResults = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Provider>, IEnumerable<ProviderResult>>(results,
opt =>
    opt.AfterMap((Providers, ProviderResults) =>
                        ProviderResults.ForEach(p => p.TradeSpecificSpeedScore) = Providers.Select(r => r.Metrics.FirstOrDefault().Data?.Trades?.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name.ToLower() == request.Query.ToLower())?.SpeedScore)));
```

and the error I get is "The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable property or indexer" which is self-explanatory. But I don't know how to solve this to map whole collection to another based on a user-input.

I want to populate TradeSpecificSpeedScore in ProviderResult with SpeedScore nested in Provider.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You usually don't need to map collections, they are already supported by AutoMapper. You only need to define the mapping from `Provider` to `ProviderResult`. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you are trying to do and show the problem you have.

Comment: I edited original question with adding models. I already have CreateMap in place from Provider to ProviderResult as shown in question.  but when I remove IEnumerable in mapper.Map, it is showing an error as my "results"( that i pass to mapper) is List<Provider>.  Basically I tried this now:  ```var providerResults = _mapper.Map<Provider, ProviderResult>(results);``` and it is giving me error for converting List<Provider> to Provider.

Answer (score 3):

You can assign values using a dictionary, so you can refer to them by key inside the mapping function.

[The docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html?highlight=items#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper) show as follows:

##### Profile

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Foo, opt => opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) => context.Items["Foo"]));
```

##### Map Call

```cs
mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(src, opt => opt.Items["Foo"] = "Bar");
```